# Using require_once for up directory not working

Tags: php, directory, require-once

I am using require_once like this

```
require_once('../mycode.php')
```

I am developing a wordpress plugin. My plugin folder is yves-slider where I have a file called yves-slider.php and a folder called admin. Inside admin folder I have a file called admin.php. I want to require file yves-slider.php in my admin.php which is located up one level directory. When I try to use

```
require_once('../yves-slider.php')
```

it gives me the following error

> Warning: require_once(../yves-slider.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\yves-slider\yves-slider-admin\yves-slider-admin.php
>   on line 4
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '../yves-slider.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\yves-slider\yves-slider-admin\yves-slider-admin.php
>   on line 4

Am I doing wrong? I am using XAMPP 3.1, I guess that's the best way to do it.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You want to make that relative to the current path the file is in:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../yves-slider.php';
```

What probably is happening is that the current path PHP looks in is *not* the path you think it is. If you are curious about what it is (the current path) you could do [`echo getcwd();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php).

Comment: What the hell I just miss one "/" in your example '/../yves-slider.php' :D thanks so much.. you answer will be checked in 6 minutes. Why the hell do I need one "/"? instead of directly '../yves-slider.php'

Comment: but i wonder, why this kind of "relative" paths work: require_once "directory/class.php"

Comment: @emfi those are relative to the current working dir and should be avoived for flexibility in your code.

Comment: well, i don't use this method, despite i don't get why there should be more flexibility?

Comment: @emfi for example when running file through the CLI the current working dir is not changed. So that means that when doing a simple `require_once "directory/class.php"` might not try to load the file in the directory you think it is.

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507